# How can I ensure an HTTP request to backend is from the same frontend origin?

Tags: php, reactjs, http

A frontend React component uses Javascript Fetch API to make a request to the backend API built on PHP. The frontend cannot use secret keys since they would be exposed in the build. What is the best way for the backend PHP code to authorize the request, ensuring that the request is authentic and from the same origin? Are there PHP variables that can reliably authenticate the request?

Comment: User authentication

Comment: @Webber User not logged in eg. login form

Comment: Recommend learning more about the concepts and looking at established systems like Symfony and Laravel at this point. There are many nuanced things like Access-Control headers and CSRF tokens that are never recommended to implement by yourself.

Comment: CORS will already do the origin part of this for you, if you're talking about AJAX/fetch requests specifically